# Associated accounts is broken for this user

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackauth, associated

When I retrieve associated accounts for [Joel Coehoorn](https://superuser.com/users/1304?tab=accounts) using [this query](http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/1dd31057-cedd-4de7-8e54-ab282c8f4e72/associated) it only includes Programmers.SE and Webmasters.SE despite the fact that I retrieved the association key from a [query to SU](http://api.superuser.com/1.0/users?min=6110&pagesize=10&page=5). The linked accounts page only shows these two sites as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.