# The associated accounts are broken once again for this same user

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackauth, associated

As I [reported before](https://stackapps.com/questions/1838/associated-accounts-is-broken-for-this-user) (and which was fixed) and [again](https://stackapps.com/questions/1976/the-associated-accounts-are-broken-again-for-this-same-user) (which was also fixed), the associated accounts are broken *once again* for for [Joel Coehoorn](https://superuser.com/users/1304?tab=accounts) using [this query](http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/1dd31057-cedd-4de7-8e54-ab282c8f4e72/associated).

***What's the deal?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joel is pulling some (non-malicious, but unusual) tricks with his OpenIds and e-mails.  This has a nasty habit of tripping up association related code.

Improvements are naturally ongoing, but its not surprising that he tends to find new edge cases for us.

Anyway, this particular issue has been fixed, although as a consequence of his SO association being restored that `association_id` is no longer valid.